# Defining a virtual attribute in Rails and making it available as a symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, symbols, getter-setter, virtual-attribute

I've defined a couple of virtual attributes, defining both the setter and the getters methods:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  def shared_to_all
    # evaluates some expression of the attribute privacy
  end

  def shared_to_friends
    # evaluates some other expression of the attribute privacy
  end

  def shared_to_all=(bool)
    # write_attribute( :privacy, ... )
  end

  def shared_to_friends=(bool)
    # write_attribute( :privacy, ... )
  end

end
```

So far so good, but I want also to make this virtual attributes available using symbols, so I can do something like `@post= Post.first; @post[:shared_to_all]= true`

[Edit:]
A Ruby approach would be to override `[]` and `[]=` operators, like in:

```
def [](shared_to_all)
  shared_to_all
end

def []=(shared_to_all, bool)
  self.shared_to_all= (bool)
end
```

But this seems to break Rails relationship methods (those brought by `has_one` - `has_many` - `belongs_to` - `has_and_belongs_to_many` directives): e.g. now `Post.first.author => nil` and `Author.first.posts => []`

Comment: Why not using `attr_accessible`? What's the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this should do it:

```
def [](attr)
  attr
end
def []=(attr, value)
  self.attr = value
end
```

Comment: Redefining `[]` and `[]=` operators seems to break relationship methods (those available via has_one - has_many - belongs_to - has_and_belongs_to_many directives): e.g. now `Post.first.author => nil` `Author.first.posts => []`